# Android x86 on Hyper-V - The mouse point not following

Tags: android-x86

I installed Android x86 on Hyper-V. I understand there are many difficulties to do this, like the display issue.

But I have to use Hyper-V since my main test environment is hosted on Hyper-V. I need the Android emulator also run on Hyper-V.

**I got only one thing not completely solved - The mouse pointer.**

The mouse pointer in Android is just not following my real mouse pointer, it is useless in Hyper-V. I noticed it is related to a module, called **hid_hyperv**. It's considered the HID driver for Hyper-V.

In Hyper-V console mode, I `rmmod` the **hid_hyperv** module, and it works fine when I use console directly.

**However**, if I **RDP** to the Hyper-V host and use the Hyper-V console, the mouse will not be captured without the "hid" module. Error message:

> Mouse not captured in remote desktop session.

I think the cause is still related to the "hid" module, as once I `insmod hid-hyperv`, the error message won't show again, just that the mouse in Android still not follow my real mouse pointer.

I am frustrated to keep digging, any one has any suggestions or workarounds for this? I don't want to compile a **hid_hyperv** module for this to resolve it. But if there is some one already did this, I am glad to know. :)